# How do I join matching attributes of all child nodes in Freeplane parent node?

Tags: xml, xpath, attributes, parent-child, freeplane

Freeplane files are XML and they apparently use `groovy` scripts, but I can't work out how to return an attribute (as a text string) using a formula in a parent node. The main help page is here: https://docs.freeplane.org/scripting/Formulas.html

Let's say I have the following tree structure:

```
rootNode
    |        +---child0
    |        |
    +--------+---child1
             |
             +---child2
```

Now, I want to add attributes to the `rootNode` and the `children` such that:

```
rootNode:
    |  +->attr[sum=children.sum(0){ it['size'].num0 }]
    |  +->attr[colours=children.join(";"){ it['colour'].text }]
    |
    |        +---child0:
    |        |     +->attr[colour='red']
    |        |     +->attr[size=3]
    |        |
    +--------+---child1:
             |     +->attr[colour='green']
             |     +->attr[size=4]
             |
             +---child2:
                   +->attr[colour='blue']
                   +->attr[size=5]
```

where `rootNode['sum'] == 12` and `rootNode['colours'] == 'red;green;blue'`.

The `sum` operation works on the numeric child attributes:
[image]

...but I don't know how to `join` the text attributes of all the children:
[image]

**I have tried:**

```
=children.join(";"){ it['colour'].text }
```

```
=children.join(";"){ it['colour'] }
```

```
=children.text(){ it['colour'].join(";") }
```

```
=children.gettext(){ it['colour'].join(";") }
```

```
=children(){ it['colour'].join(";") }
```

```
=children.details(){ it['colour'].join(";") }
```

...and so far the *only* formula that *does not* result in an error:

```
=children.each{ it['colour'].text }.join(';')
```

[image]

**Any other suggestions?**